# Git commit not working with Atom on Mac

Tags: git, atom-editor

I installed git on my mac and now I started using it from my terminal. I also configured it this way

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

but when i use git commit this is what I get

```
atom --wait: atom: command not found 
error: There was a problem with the editor 'atom --wait'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

and now I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you install the `atom` shell command? It's not there unless you run the install command. It is in the Atom application's menus.

Comment: Installing the shell commands made everything work, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the full path to atom.

Answer (score 0):

i try all methods and I could not get a proper answer;

but This method answered me:
(my cmd is cmder )

unset core.editor : `git config --global --unset core.editor`

and then run code.