# Git config error - atom editor

Tags: git, git-commit, git-config

When I try to commit files I am getting the error below and I am pretty new to git.

hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... atom --wait: atom: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'atom --wait'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try `git status` and print the results to your questions. Also can you write out the complete command you tried along with the complete result?... I assume you have tried to close Atom if you have it open!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git commit not working with Atom on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782004/git-commit-not-working-with-atom-on-mac)